# Deploy in cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

***I have this trace in jboss in cloudbees:***

```
21:29:57,462 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."webapp.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."webapp.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "webapp.war" of deployment "app.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_35]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not get class configuration for 
    br.com.mystudies.service.persistence.BackLogDAOBean due to the following errors: 
    Can't find a deployment unit named mystudies-persistence at subdeployment 
    "webapp.war" of deployment "app.ear"
```

***but I downloaded  the war file in jenkins and deployed in local environment:***

```
18:19:51,614 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH00130:Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
18:19:52,104 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH00400:Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

more log...

```
18:19:54,399 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-6) HHH00232:Schema update complete
18:19:56,371 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) registering web context: /mystudies-web-1.0.0
18:19:56,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Deployed "mystudies-web-1.0.0.war"
```

the deploy hasn't problem.

I searched this problem in google, but no answer.

someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to ensure you can running the same version locally where possible. It is a bit hard to know what it could be from that. Currently only the web profile is supported.

Comment: the solution for this problem was put the persistence.xml in META-INF in web module.But I didn't understand why this don't work in service module [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-Deployment) have all places where the file will be deployed.

Comment: Great! You should put your comment as the answer!